# Which WP plugin should I use to generate "popular" posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

As mentioned in my previous question, I happened to see this site 22words.com and just can't figure out a few things:

1) in the source code, it seems the name of the WP theme is "twentytwo" but there's no such a theme in existence. How could this be possible? Maybe they used another theme and renamed it to "twentytwo"? Is that do-able? How to actually do it? Or maybe they just custom-made the theme and gave it a name called "twentytwo"?

2) Some posts have a big green "read more" button (e.g. twentytwowords.com/if-you-have-keys-and-a-purse-or-know-someone-who-does-youve-lived-some-version-of-this-story/) how does this work? If I want to mimic this approach for long posts, what's the best way of doing it?

3) The top navigation bar have drop-down menus such as "latest posts" and "popular posts" in the respective categories. Is all this a gimmick or not? I mean, what's being shown are actually "latest" and "popular" posts, or is it just BS and there's no stats to back up "popular"? If it's not gimmick, then how is it implemented? Which plug-ins are in place to calculate traffic and generate "popular" posts?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Telling people to go look at some web site and explain how some of the features are implemented is not a valid question for Stack Overflow's format. Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and identify a coding question in specific terms, referencing the code you've provided. Please read this advice on [ask] and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: Well, I guess I made an "innocent crime". I'm new to this great community and haven't got the time to carefully read all the rules yet so apologies if I have broken the rules. Just a quick one: if I saw something interesting and want to implement it but don't have an idea, can I still ask for tips/hints? I mean, otherwise it would be really difficult if I don't even know where to get started...

Comment: No, if you're looking for "tips/hints", this really isn't the right place. Stack Overflow is [a question-and-answer resource, not a help forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92115/228805). It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers, not a place to ask open-ended questions seeking broad overviews, tutorials, introductory info, or general pointers about getting started. Please read the [About] page for a better understanding of the site's format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

lets get this done quickly :)

1.) I guess they have made an own theme and named it that way.

2.) In the editor you have a "readmore" tag 
[image]
if you click this you will insert a special line / markup.
Now your theme nees a call for this line
"Excerpts (teasers) can be shown on WordPress through two methods:

The first, keeping the the_content() template tag and inserting a quicktag called more at your desired "cut-off" point when editing the post.
The second, by replacing the the_content() template tag with the_excerpt()."
Here is all you need: [Link to wordpress documentation the excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

3.) There are quite a lot of ways to do that. You could order posts by popularity by the number of comments or the number of views or the number of shares. There a loads of tutorials on the web to do so. It's so simple it would be sad to use a plugin AND: you could learn a lot from it... 
tutorial by view is here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/
tutorial by number of comments is here: http://www.jafaloo.com/how-to-display-popular-posts-in-wordpress/

all the best
fabian

Comment: This thread has been put on hold. how can I close it? Thanks!